# Jquery : find text from string which is not in DIV tag

Tags: jquery

```
if x = 'FName LName<div class="soc-net-not" id="social_network_notification_853">3</div>';
```

How do I extract only the portion 'FName LName' from the above string. I dont want div tags or its innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = 'FName LName<div class="soc-net-not" id="social_network_notification_853">3</div>';
var text = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("<") - 1); // FName LName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 'FName LName<div class="soc-net-not" id="social_network_notification_853">3</div>';

var y = x.split('<')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

As always, if it gets more complex, parse the HTML

```
var text = $('<div />').html(x).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3; // only get text nodes
}).text();
```

Or in your case, this would suffice as well:

```
var text = $('<div />').html(x).contents().first().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var text = $('<div/>').html(x).find('div').remove().end().text()
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8PGht/)